# Printing the value of a function crashes Mathematica

Tags: functions, crash, debugging

I define `SolVm1`:

```
SolVm1 = C[1] HermiteH[-(em/a1), (a1^2 x - a0 delta)/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] + C[2] Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/2, (a1^2 x - a0 delta)^2/(a1^3 sigma)] + HermiteH[-(em/a1), (a1^2 x - a0 delta)/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] Inactive[Integrate][-((2 a1^2 Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/2, (a0 delta - a1^2 K[1])^2/(a1^3 sigma)] (a0 ep lambda + (-1 + a1 ep lambda) K[1]))/(em (em - ep) (a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma] HermiteH[-((a1 + em)/a1), (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[1])/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/2, (a0 delta - a1^2 K[1])^2/(a1^3 sigma)] + HermiteH[-(em/a1), (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[1])/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] Hypergeometric1F1[1 + em/(2 a1), 3/2, (a0 delta - a1^2 K[1])^2/(a1^3 sigma)] (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[1])))), {K[1], 1, x}] + Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/2, (a1^2 x - a0 delta)^2/(a1^3 sigma)] Inactive[Integrate][(2 a1^2 HermiteH[-(em/a1), (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[2])/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] (a0 ep lambda + (-1 + a1 ep lambda) K[2]))/(em (em - ep) (a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma] HermiteH[-((a1 + em)/a1), (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[2])/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] Hypergeometric1F1[em/(2 a1), 1/2, (a0 delta - a1^2 K[2])^2/(a1^3 sigma)] + HermiteH[-(em/a1), (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[2])/(a1^(3/2) Sqrt[sigma])] Hypergeometric1F1[1 + em/(2 a1), 3/2, (a0 delta - a1^2 K[2])^2/(a1^3 sigma)] (-a0 delta + a1^2 K[2]))), {K[2], 1, x}];
```

I define `SolVp3`:

```
SolVp3 = (2 (a1 ep x + a0 delta - a1 em (a1 ep x + a0 (a1 + ep + delta)) lambda))/(
   a1 ep (a1 + ep) (-em + ep)) + C[2] Hypergeometric1F1[ep/(2 a1), 1/2, (a1^2 x - a0 delta)^2/(a1^3 sigma)];
```

I define these functions:

```
Vm[x_] = SolVm1;
Vp[x_] = SolVp3 /. C[2] -> C[3];
Jx[x_] = em*Vm[x] + ep*Vp[x];
Jxx[x_] = em*D[Vm[x], x] + ep*D[Vp[x], x];
Jpi[x_] = Vm[x] + Vp[x];
Jpipi[x_] = D[Vm[x], x] + D[Vp[x], x];
```

I find the constants in my expressions:

```
constants = Solve[{Jx[xhat] == 0, Jxx[xhat] == 0, Jpi[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi))*xhat}, {C[1], C[2], C[3]}];
```

I replace the constants:

```
SolJx[x_] = Jx[x] /. constants[[1]];
SolJxx[x_] = Jxx[x] /. constants[[1]];
SolJpi[x_] = Jpi[x] /. constants[[1]];
SolJpipi[x_] = Jpipi[x] /. constants[[1]];
```

When I try to see the value of `SolJpipi[x]`, Mathematica crashes:

```
SolJpipi[x]
```

Comment: It doesn't crash for me in 13.2.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: It doesn't crash for me either in 12.0.0.0.